# ANDROID - send List to PHP via VOLLEY

Tags: php, android, arraylist, android-volley

Hello I have a List named StudentBATCH_LIST that I populated with the contents from a csv using:

```
    File csvFILE = new File(getFILE_PATH());
    try {
        CSVReader csvREAD = new CSVReader(new 
        FileReader(csvFILE.getAbsolutePath()));
        String[] csvLINE;
        int skip = 0;
        while((csvLINE = csvREAD.readNext())!=null)
        {
            if(skip > 0)//becasue first line is column headers
            {
                String PARAM_USER_ID = csvLINE[0];
                String PARAM_STUD_FIRSTNAME = csvLINE[1];
                String PARAM_STUD_LASTNAME = csvLINE[2];
                String PARAM_STUD_MIDDLENAME = csvLINE[3];
                String PARAM_STUD_EMAIL = PARAM_USER_ID+EMAIL_S;

                AdminAddStudentBATCH_CONFIG STUD_OBJECT = new AdminAddStudentBATCH_CONFIG(PARAM_USER_ID,
                        PARAM_STUD_FIRSTNAME,
                        PARAM_STUD_LASTNAME,
                        PARAM_STUD_MIDDLENAME,
                        PARAM_STUD_EMAIL);
                StudentBATCH_LIST.add(STUD_OBJECT);
            }
            else
            {
                skip ++;
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        volleyErrorClass.catchInvalidResponse(e.toString(),AdminAddStudentBATCH.this);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        volleyErrorClass.catchInvalidResponse(e.toString(),AdminAddStudentBATCH.this);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        volleyErrorClass.catchInvalidResponse(e.toString(),AdminAddStudentBATCH.this);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        volleyErrorClass.catchInvalidResponse(e.toString(),AdminAddStudentBATCH.this);
    }
```

I want to know how do I pass this List to PHP with volley. How do I do it? Also how do I decode this in PHP.

Anyway the tags of the values in the List are
                            `USER_ID`,
                            `STUD_FIRSTNAME`,
                            `STUD_LASTNAME`,
                            `STUD_MIDDLENAME`,
                            `STUD_EMAIL`

Comment: I would like to recommend you to convert this list to `JSON` Object and send to the server.

Comment: You should send the csv file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purpose of your application, I'd convert the StudentBATCH_LIST to JSON array, and then deserialize that array on your web api.

Here are brief steps:

**Step 1. Add Volley and GSON dependencies to app level build.gradle file:**

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
}
```

**Step 2. convert list to JSON array using GSON:**

```
String studentBatchListString = new Gson().toJson(students);
```

**Step 3. POST studentBatchListString to your web api ("send to PHP")**

```
String url = "http://yourdomain.com/post.php";
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, 
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            // response
            Log.d("Response", response);
        }
    }, 
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
             // error
             Log.d("Error.Response", response);
       }
    }
) {     
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {  
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
            params.put("students_batch_list", studentBatchListString);  
            return params;  
    }
};
queue.add(postRequest);
```

**Step 4. deserialize on PHP side:**

```
$content = $_POST['students_batch_list'];
$json = json_decode($content, true);
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    $firstname = $value["firstname"];
    $lastname = $value["lastname"];
    // perform other actions.
}
```